# how to retrieve .keydown() function

Tags: jquery

How is it possible to retrieve all functionality from a .keydown() function?

I need to retrieve the function, clear it and add a new function and in the end roll back to the origin function

I don't have the origin function as a handler function so I can't use bind() and unbind() I think..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
//This will retrieve all the keydown events attached to the element
var originalKeydownEvents = $('elementSelector').data("events").keydown;

//Here unbind all the keydown handlers and bind the required keydown handler
$("elementSelector").unbind('keydown').keydown(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  //Do you stuff here

  //Then finally attach the original events
  jQuery.each(originalKeydownEvents, function(key, handler) {
     $this.keydown(handler);
  });

});
```